# Comparing Two Excel workbooks and copying matched data to third workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to compare two workbooks in excel and have matching column data copy the entire row into a new third workbook. Ex:

Compare

Workbook_1 column A to Workbook_2 column A, if there is a names match, copy the entire row of matching Workbook_1 column A data to the third Workbook (Workbook_3).

This is the code I have:

```
Sub RunMe()
Dim lRow, a As Long

Sheets("Workbook_1").Select
lRow = Range("A1").End(alDown).Row

For Each cell In Range("A2:A" & lRow)
    a = 2
    Do
        If cell.Value = Workbook("Workbook_2").Cells(a, "A").Value Then
            cell.EntireRow.Copy Workbook("Workbook_3").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(alUp).Offset(1, 0)
        End If
        a = a + 1
    Loop Until IsEmpty(Workbook("Workbook_2").Cells(a, "A"))
Next

End Sub
```

I found this code in another website, and I edited the workbook name and created the module for it, run it, but it is not working.

Any help would be appreciated, I am not very good in excel, so can you kindly explain as you would for beginner.

Thanks!

Comment: Where is your code giving an error and what error is coming up? To begin with you say you want to loop through column A but you keep referencing column E.

Comment: Hi, There is no error, when I run the code it takes few minutes to run then stops and nothing happening, no copy or anything to the workbook_3 - Regarding Col A & E it's entered correctly as A, But I typed here the original code that I found edited some to make it easy to see if it's my mistake or the code itself.

Comment: You're referring to `Sheets` in your code, yet you talk about `Workbooks`? A workbook is an Excel file, which can contain a number of sheets (the "tabs" at the bottom of the file). Which one do you mean?

Comment: I mean workbook (file), not sheet.

Comment: I would suggest editing your post to show exactly what you're trying to run as this will make it easier to help you. Are you trying to search the entire column for matches or only if row x on book1 is equal to row x on book 2?

Comment: I have edited the post, I am trying  to search the entire column for matches, and if found copy the entire row to a new workbook. Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your current code won't do anything close to what you want it to. Try the below code and see if it works for you. I tried to add some comments explaining what the code is doing. Be sure to change the workbook and worksheet names in the code to match your actual books.

```
Sub RunMe()

    Dim wbk1 As Workbook, wbk2 As Workbook, wbk3 As Workbook
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, ws3 As Worksheet
    Dim lRow1 As Long, lCol1 As Long, lRow3 As Long, x As Long
    Dim myValue As String
    Dim Found As Range

    Set wbk1 = Workbooks("Workbook_1.xlsm") 'Be sure to change these to your actual workbook names
    Set ws1 = wbk1.Worksheets("Sheet1") 'Be sure to change these to your actual worksheet names

    Set wbk2 = Workbooks("Workbook_2.xlsm")
    Set ws2 = wbk2.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    Set wbk3 = Workbooks("Workbook_3.xlsm")
    Set ws3 = wbk3.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    'Using a with block means we don't have to define any range coming from book1. ws1.Range("A2") is the same as .Range("A2")
    With ws1
        'Find last row in ws1 Col A
        lRow1 = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        'Find last column in ws1
        lCol1 = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
            After:=.Cells(1, 1), _
            LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
            LookAt:=xlPart, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
            MatchCase:=False).Column
        'Start loop to search through all values in column A
        For x = 2 To lRow1
            myValue = .Cells(x, 1).Value
            'Look for value in Workbook2 column A
            Set Found = ws2.Cells.Find(What:=myValue, _
                After:=ws2.Cells(1, 1), _
                LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                MatchCase:=False)
            'If Found is not nothing then do something
            If Not Found Is Nothing Then
                'Find last row in ws3 Col A
                lRow3 = ws3.Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
                'Instead of using .copy saying "This Range = That Range" is much faster
                ws3.Range(ws3.Cells(lRow3 + 1, 1), ws3.Cells(lRow3 + 1, lCol1)).Value = .Range(.Cells(x, 1), .Cells(x, lCol1)).Value
            End If
        Next x
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank for the code, Can I check with you the name change, Is this correct:     Set wbk3 = Workbooks("ReportTable.xlsm")
    Set ws3 = wbk3.Worksheets("ReportTableSheet")

Comment: @user3103193 yes that looks correct. Just be sure your workbooks are saved as .xlsm (Macro enabled)

Comment: Yes they are saved as .xlsm  - but i have the following error when I run it: Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range. do you know what's wrong.

Comment: @user3103193 Do you have all of your workbooks open when you run it? Then what line gets highlighted when it throws up the error?

Comment: Yes they are all open, and here is the line causing the error: Set wbk1 = Workbooks("Exped.xlsm") 'Be sure to change these to your actual workbook names.

Comment: @user3103193 that should only happen if you don't have that workbook open or it's named something else. When you look at the top of the screen your workbook is named "Exped.xlsm" ? The default would be .xlsx

Comment: I closed all files and reopened them, run it and I got "The  macros for these project are disabled" even that the extension is xlsm, How to enable  macros.

Comment: The online help say "Close the document, and then reopen it with Enable Macros." but I did reopen them already.

Comment: @user3103193 When you first open a macro enabled workbook you should get a yellowish orange pop up asking if you want to enable them. If you're not seeing that you may have macros automatically disabled in your options. Check that and try again.

Comment: Ok, I sorted it, Thanks a lot

Comment: It's running fine except the report shows half the raw not all of them.there are 8 columns and only 4 is copied.

Comment: @user3103193 does all your data have headers? If not I just edited the code to change the way we find last column. Give it a shot.

Comment: Yes this one is perfect, Thanks a lot.